# Mix web api controllers and site controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am fiddeling with the new wep api in mvc 4 beta and adding some new api controllers to my existing mvc site. Problem is I can't name the web api controllers the same as my existing controllers. For now I have given them names like ProductApiController but that is not very restlike. What is a good strategy for namegiving of these new controllers when adding them to an existing mvc site?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Problem is I can't name the web api controllers the same as my existing controllers.

You could have your API controllers with the same name as your existing controllers. Just put them in a different namespace to make the compiler happy.

Example:

```
namespace MyAppName.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = productsRepository.GetProducts();
            return View(products);
        }
    }
}
```

and the API controller:

```
namespace MyAppName.Controllers.Api
{
    public class ProductsController: ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            return productsRepository.GetProducts();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you have: `/products` and `/api/products` respectively to work with.

Comment: So then I can add a api subfolder in the controllers folder and add the api controllers there?

Comment: @TT., yes, it's a possibility.

Comment: Or maybe an Area for the web api is more appropriate?

Comment: @TT., yeah whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: FYI, I've had trouble getting this to work and haven't been able to pinpoint the issue. When I use jquery to `GET` `/api/products` the server returns a 301 with the new location at `/api/products/` which returns with a 404. With a clean new web api project I can get it to work, but once I start adding references from nuget/solution it breaks.

Comment: How would you configure the routes for this design in the AreaRegistration class?  I am unable to map to the controller in the API namespace.