# Can I have both a Controller and an ApiController for the same thing?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf-web-api

I've just started to use the VS 2012 RC, and I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application in which I plan to provide both an HTML-based user interface and a WebApi-based programming interface.

For my HTML website, I have a controller and view for each of my models (MVC!), and the routing works "by convention" so that, for example, the URL `/client` hooks up to my `ClientController`. My `ClientController` derives from `Controller`.

For my API, I will create new controllers that derive from `ApiController`. I naturally want my API URLs to be similar to my HTML URLs, so I'd like the client info to be available at `/api/client`. However, with the by-convention routing, that would suggest that I need an ApiController named `ClientController`. And I already have a `ClientController` class.

How do I deal with this? Do I need custom routing? Do I put the API classes in different namespace so that I can give them the same name?

**Update:** this question seems to suggest that a different namespace for my API controllers is all I need: [Mix web api controllers and site controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353427/mix-web-api-controllers-and-site-controllers)

Comment: Have you looked at [MVC areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx)?

Comment: @gordonml: Thanks - I just did, and it seems to be sotra, kinda useful. However I can't help feeling that it's a little overblown for what I need to achieve.

Comment: Does IsAjaxRequest work for your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681563/detecting-isajaxrequest-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-form-plugin-file-upload

Comment: @kenny: no, I'm trying not to "bend" stuff by writing code - I'm just trying to establish the correct way to do it "by convention", which seems to be to use a separate namespace for my API controllers (see Update).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All it requires is for the controller classes to be in a different namespace, and all is well.

Using MVC areas would also work (as suggested in gordonml's comment), but this effectively puts the controllers in different namespaces, so it's a more formal way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/28/using-razor-together-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) which illustrates how an Api controller could serve Razor views as well. Basically he uses the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to parse the Razor view end serve it.

Comment: Err... thanks, but that looks like the polar opposite of what I'm trying to acheive, in that I'm trying to "do it the MVC4 way" rather than bend it to do something that it wasn't designed for.

Comment: Besides which, my two URLs will do completely different things. My normal URL presents a user interface to do all sorts of stuff. My API URL simply provides access to the data. So it's not really a question of returning "the same content" in different formats.

Comment: Well in this case the `/api` prefix shouldn't bother you as it performs something completely different from the rest of the application. It allows you to clearly separate the API part from the website.

Comment: And also, the URLs are different anyway, since one is prefixed with "/api/". I *do* expect to have two different controllers for these two purposes - I'm just not clear about how to get the routing hooked up without resorting to wiring it up myself.

Comment: I think our comments "crossed". I agree that the "/api/" bit isn't a problem. My problem is that I appear to need two different controllers with the same name. I don't know how best to avoid a naming clash, nor how the framework is going to distinguish between them and pick the right one.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for step by step guidance on how to do this on WebApi project:

1. Create two folders / namespaces, namely: `ControllersApi` and `ControllersWeb`
2. Right click on `ControllersWeb` and go `Add -> Controller` and select `MVC 5 Controller - Empty`. This will add all other dependencies if you didn't have them in your WebApi project.
3. Your `RouteConfig` will now register those classes that inherit from `Controller` base class. You'll likely need to add link to default Controller, by editing defaults to say: `defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

That's it, you can now run site and use both API and Web controllers.